# Add C++ code subfolders recursively to XCode 7 for compilation

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I must be missing something here. I've tried dragging and dropping folders to create both "groups" and "folder references", but neither operation will pull out the .cpp files contained within these folders and actually **add them to my Compile Sources** for the target. I'm sure there's a better way to do this than to walk through all of the subfolders dragging across each .cpp file one at a time? Am I crazy?

Answer (score 1):

For a folder of source code files, you should create "groups". Folder references are for folders of files you're not going to be editing in Xcode, such as folders of audio and image files. I'm not sure why the files in the folder aren't being added to the Compile Sources build phase if you added the folder as a "group".

If the files aren't being automatically added to the Compile Sources build phase, a better way to add them is to go the Compile Sources build phase and click the Add button.

[image]

A sheet will open that mirrors the project navigator.

[image]

From there you should be able to select multiple files to add by shift-clicking or command-clicking. I'm not sure if this is the best way to add files, but it's better than dragging one file at a time.